Unable to start neo4j server with Java 21
When starting neo4j server version 5.19.0 (neo4j-community-5.19.0-unix.tar.gz) with java 21 I'm getting the following error thrown by jersey-server v2.34 dependency:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 65                                                                                                                             
        at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:196) ~[jersey-server-2.34.jar:?]   

It is stated that java 21 is supported since Neo4j 5.14 but I also see that java 21 is supported since Jersey 2.40
https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/modules-and-dependencies.html
Is there a specific thing to make neo4j run under java 21?
I don't have control over which dependencies are pulled or not, so I don't know what to do...
Any ideas?
Thanks :)

How have you tried to start neo4j? How have you verified that java 21 is actually being used?

Is it a spring boot project? Maybe it’s because jdk21 does not support the selected springboot version. You can try spring boot 3.2 +
